# Setting up DHCP in OpenSolaris

Tags: dhcp, opensolaris, packages

I have searched but am unable to find the specific packages that are needed to set up DHCP in OpenSolaris (I am using 2008.11). Are they included in the default installation? Or, we have to use pkg install?

Comment: do you mean setting up OpenSolaris as a DHCP server, or simply to have it pull an IP as a DHCP client?

Comment: yeah, I meant to set it up as a DHCP server.

Answer (score 2):

The packages you need are:

- SUNWdhcm                         DHCP Manager
- SUNWdhcsb                        Binary File Format Data Module for BOOTP/DHCP Services
- SUNWdhcsr                        BOOTP/DHCP Server Services, (Root)
- SUNWdhcsu                        BOOTP/DHCP Server Services, (Usr)

I'm not sure if they are included in the default install, but a quick

`pkginfo | grep DHCP`

Should tell you if you have them.

Answer (score 1):

To set it up as a server you need to install some packages which aren't installed by default:

```
pkg install SUNWdhcm SUNWdhcs
```

(if you want to get better performance, add the SUNWdhcsb which stores the dhcp info in a binary format)

If you want to do a search for a file or directory in OpenSolaris, use

```
pkg search -r -I dhcp
```

The -I flag makes it case insensitive, and the -r flag searches the remote package repository (if you are running OpenSolaris 2009.06 and later, you can skip the -r flag, it is the default)

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the guide I've made on setting up a DHCP server in (Open)Solaris. It's on Sun's BigAdmin site: http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/content/submitted/config_dhcp_server.jsp.
It should contain the most basic informations on how to get started with a Solaris based DHCP server.